# Through what algebraic properties is the following simplification occurring? Please show it step-by-step.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How is $ \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{x}{1+t}}} * \dfrac{1}{1+t} $ simplified to $\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{t+1} }$. What algebraic properties does this occur through? Please show the simplification step-by-step. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand why $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+t}}(1+t)=\sqrt{t+1}$, for all $t$ greater than $-1$?

Comment: @GitGud No, I don't.

Comment: Note that $t+1=\sqrt{1+t}\sqrt{1+t}$. Do you see how this helps?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip over the $\sqrt {1+t}$ to the numerator as it is in the denominator of the denominator.

So it can be written as $\frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{2\sqrt{x}}*\frac{1}{1+t}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+t}}$

Hope it helps!